# unable to install networkit package in pycharm

Tags: python, macos, pycharm, anaconda, networkit

I am a newbie to python and pycharm. I am unable to install networkit package in pycharm. The following is the error I am getting. Anyone with knowledge on this? Thanks in advance

```
Solving environment: ...working... failed PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:
  - networkit Current channels:
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/osx-64
  - https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda-fusion/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to
    https://anaconda.org and use the search bar at the top of the page.
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [networkit](https://anaconda.org/vgauthier/networkit) is a private package. Use the following command from a Conda console to install it:

```
conda install -c vgauthier networkit
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing this. Conda install always seems to have a syntax error problem. I installed conda using pip3. However, it dint seem to work either.

Comment: Try installing Anaconda as a separate Python installation, and installing this package from there.